# Define an active character inside a definition

Tags: macros, tex-core, e-tex

```
\def\test{\catcode`!=\active \def!{test}}
```

Of course the above code would not work because nothing is executed when TeX is reading the replacement text of a macro definition.  `!` gets catcode 12 anyway. I've tried a search on this site and someone suggested using `\scantokens`. As far as I know, `\scantokens` is an expandable command which reads the following token list, stores it in a pseudo-file and then inputs it, so the tokens get re-tokenized according to the new catcodes. However, the following code still fails and I can't figure out why.

```
\def\test{\catcode`!=\active \scantokens{\def!}{test}}
\test
```

I get the error of "runaway definition".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [e-TeX reference](http://archiv.dante.de/projects/nts/archiv/etex-ref-prel.html#scantokens) defines `\scantokens` as follows:

> `\scantokens`, when followed by a *<general text>*, decomposes the *<balanced text>* of the *<general text>* into the corresponding sequence of characters as if the *<balanced text>* were written unexpanded to a file; it then uses TeX's `\input` mechanism to re-process these characters under the current `\catcode` regime.

So the `\def!` part of your macro is processed as if it were defined in an extra file that is then `\input` into your main file. This includes the use of an internal end-fo-file marker when the whole *<balanced text>* has been processed.

In *The TeXbook*, p. 206, Knuth makes a note on file reading and `\outer` macros (thanks to GuM for pointing this out):

> An `\outer` macro cannot appear in an argument (not even when `\par` is allowed), nor can it appear in the parameter text or the replacement text of a definition [...] The end of an input file or alignment template is also considered to be `\outer` in this sense; for example, a file shouldn't end in the middle of a definition.

This is exactly the problem you run into here. TeX is still scanning the definition of `!` when the end of file after `\scantokens` occurs. It then complains about `File ended while scanning definition of !`. You can see the same behavior and error message if you replace `\scantokens{\def!}` by an actual `\input` were the input file includes only `\def!`.

Bruno Le Floch found a nice way to get around this problem by using a `\let` instead of `\def` to define `!`:

```
\def\bangdef{test}
\def\test{\catcode`!=\active \scantokens{\let!}\bangdef}
\test
```

---

For completeness, here are two standard tricks that do not make use of `\scantokens`. One way to get the desired result is by defining `\test` in a regime which has the correct catcode already applied:

```
\begingroup
\catcode`!=\active
\gdef\test{\catcode`!=\active \def!{test}}
\endgroup
\test
\show!
```

Instead of the `\gdef` you could also save the current catcode of `!` and restore it after the definition of `\test`.

Another common trick is to change the lowercase code of an active character, here `~`, to the character code of the character to be made active, and then use `\lowercase` to apply this change:

```
\def\test{%
  \begingroup
  \lccode`\~=`\!
  \lowercase{\endgroup \catcode`\!=\active \def~}{test}%
}
\test
\show!
```

Comment: On `\scantokens`, it is possible to avoid the issues with end-of-file but only by using an assignment. It's well-established that `\scantokens` is a bit 'fragile': it needs careful handling.

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks, I updated the second example. Could you explain what kind of assignment you mean for the `\scantokens` approach?

Comment: Typically just `\everyeof{\noexpand}` but one can be more sophisticated (see the `expl3` code for `\tl_rescan:nn`).

Comment: As for a reference for the rule that forbids definitions to continue past the end of a file, see _The TeXbook_, p. 206, lines 7-13.  If you want, I can insert the reference directly into your answer.

Comment: Amusingly `\scantokens{\let\foo}\bar` works, so one way could be to `\def\temporary{test}` and `\expandafter\let\scantokens{!}\temporary`.

Answer (score 2):

OpTeX defines its `\adef` macro using `\directlua`:

```
   \_doc ------------------------------
   \`\adef` `<char>{<body>}` defines active `<char>` as <body> and then
   puts the <char> as active character. I.e. the `<body>` can include the
   <char> as non-active charter (if it is non-active before `\adef`).
   For example `\adef ?{\,?}`.
   If the character is special, you can escape it, for example `\adef\%{...}`.
   The space can be declared by `\adef{ }{<body>}`.
   You can declare a macro with parameters too, for example
   `\adef @#1{...#1...}`. You can use prefixes `\protected`, `\global`,
   `\long` before `\adef`, they behave like prefixes before `\def`.
   \_cod ------------------------------

\_def\_adef#1#2#{\_adefA{#1}{#2}}
\_def\_adefA#1#2#3{\_ea\_def\_directlua{tex.cprint(13,"\_luaescapestring{\_csstring#1}")}#2{#3}%
   \_catcode`#1=13 }
\_public \adef ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use etex or pdftex.

```
\def\test{\catcode`!=\active 
          \begingroup\endlinechar-1
                     \everyeof{{test}\endgroup}\scantokens{\gdef!}}

\test

\tt
\meaning!

\bye
```

[image]

---

Less original, and dropping the idea to end the scantokens argument before replacement text:

```
\def\test{\catcode`!=\active 
          \scantokens{\def!{test}\relax}}% \relax to absorb an EOL space token

\tt

+++\test+++

\show!

\bye
```

Produces

```
> !=macro:
->test.
l.10 \show!
```

Comment: The first method has the advantage that the definition of `!` can easily be made to use itself with catcode 12, for example try with `\everyeof{{!!!}\endgroup}`. This will define the active `!` to non-active `!!!`.

Answer (score 0):

### "Academic" info:

You can (ab)use `\futurelet` for getting rid of end-of-file-markers that come into being due to `\scantokens` or due to the `\input`-primitive—in LaTeX the `\input`-primitive is renamed to `\@@input` and the control sequence `\input` is redefined:

```tex
% Characters of category 0, 5, 9, 14 and 15 don't make it into explicit 
% character tokens, thus allow syntax both with explicit character tokens
% and control symbol tokens.
%
% E.g., under normal circumstances you can't do
%    \DefineActiveChar{%}{<prefixes like \global>}<parameter text>{<replacement text}%
% , but you can do
%    \DefineActiveChar{\%}{<prefixes like \global>}<parameter text>{<replacement text}%
% .

% Reading a single space from a line of .tex-input, be it a real text file
% or be it with \scantokens' faking of unexpanded-writing and then inputting
% of a text file, requires special attention because at the time of
% pre-processing a line of .tex-input all space-characters at the end of the
% line get stripped off.
% With some TeX-implementations this is also the case with the horizontal-tab-
% character.
% Thus writing and reading a space-character to/from external text file
% requires appending an additional comment-character.
% At least with writing and reading linefed and carriage return
% special attention might be required, too.

\newtoks\scratchtoks
\def\thescratchtoks{\the\scratchtoks}%
\long\def\firstoftwo#1#2{#1}%
\long\def\secondoftwo#1#2{#2}%

\def\GatherActiveCharacterAsRelax#1{%
  % #1 = active character token to (re)define
  \let#1=\relax\NeutraLizeEOFMarker{#1}%
}%
\def\NeutraLizeEOFMarker#1#2{%
  % #1 = active character token to (re)define
  % #2 = letter X or - in case X is the active character to redefine - active X
  %      ; ensures that in case #1 is space that space is not removed 
  %        during TeX's pre-processing of lines of input
  \endgroup
  \begingroup
  \let#1=\relax
  \scratchtoks={\GatherDefinitionPrefixAndDefine{#1}}%
  \everyeof={}%
  \futurelet\scratchmacro\thescratchtoks
}%
\long\def\GatherDefinitionPrefixAndDefine#1#2{%
  % #1 = active character token to (re)define
  % #2 = prefixes for `\def` like `\global` or `\long`
  \endgroup#2\def#1%
}%

\def\DefineActiveChar#1{%
  % #1 = character or one-letter-control-sequence for alphabetic constant
  \begingroup
  \escapechar=-1\relax
  \newlinechar=-1\relax
  \endlinechar=-1\relax
  \catcode`\^=7\relax
  \catcode`\X=11\relax
  \catcode`#1=\active
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\GatherActiveCharacterAsRelax\expandafter\noexpand
  \scantokens
  \csname \ifnum`#1=10 first\else second\fi oftwo\endcsname
  {%
    \expandafter{\expandafter^\expandafter^JX}%
  }{%
    \csname \ifnum`#1=13 first\else second\fi oftwo\endcsname
    {%
      \expandafter{\expandafter^\expandafter^MX}%
    }{%
      \expandafter{\string#1X}%
    }%
  }%
}%

{\catcode`!=\active \outer\gdef!{Huh?}}%

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\DefineActiveChar{!}{\long}#1#2{ACTIVE EXCLAMATION MARK Arg1: #1 test Arg2: #2}
\begingroup \catcode`!=\active \show!\endgroup
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\DefineActiveChar{A}{\long}#1#2{ACTIVE A Arg1: #1 test Arg2: #2}
\begingroup \catcode`A=\active \showA\endgroup
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\DefineActiveChar{\!}{\long}#1#2{ACTIVE EXCLAMATION MARK AGAIN Arg1: #1 TEST Arg2: #2}
\begingroup \catcode`!=\active \show!\endgroup
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\DefineActiveChar{\%}{\long}#1#2{ACTIVE PERCENT Arg1: #1 Arg2: #2}
\begingroup \catcode`\%=\active \show%\endgroup
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\DefineActiveChar{\{}{\long}#1#2{ACTIVE CURLY LEFT BRACE Arg1: #1 Arg2: #2}
\begingroup \catcode`\{=\active \show{\endgroup
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\DefineActiveChar{\}}{\long}#1#2{ACTIVE CURLY RIGHT BRACE Arg1: #1 Arg2: #2}
\begingroup \catcode`\}=\active \show}\endgroup
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\DefineActiveChar{\#}{\long}#1#2{ACTIVE HASH Arg1: #1 Arg2: #2}
\begingroup \catcode`\#=\active \show#\endgroup
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\DefineActiveChar{\ }{\long}#1#2{ACTIVE SPACE Arg1: #1 Arg2: #2}
\begingroup \catcode`\ =\active\show \endgroup
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\DefineActiveChar{ }{\long}#1#2{ACTIVE SPACE AGAIN Arg1: #1 Arg2: #2}
\begingroup \catcode`\ =\active\show \endgroup
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\DefineActiveChar{\^^I}{\long}#1#2{ACTIVE HORIZONTAL TAB Arg1: #1 Arg2: #2}
\begingroup \catcode`\^^I=\active\show^^I\endgroup
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\DefineActiveChar{\\}{\long}#1#2{ACTIVE BACKSLASH Arg1: #1 Arg2: #2}
\begingroup \catcode`\/=0 \catcode`\\=\active/show\/endgroup
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\DefineActiveChar{\$}{\long}#1#2{ACTIVE DOLLAR Arg1: #1 Arg2: #2}
\begingroup \catcode`\$=\active\show$\endgroup
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\DefineActiveChar{\&}{\long}#1#2{ACTIVE AMPERSAND Arg1: #1 Arg2: #2}
\begingroup \catcode`\&=\active\show&\endgroup
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\DefineActiveChar{\^}{\long}#1#2{ACTIVE CARET Arg1: #1 Arg2: #2}
\begingroup \catcode`\^=\active\show^\endgroup
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\DefineActiveChar{\_}{\long}#1#2{ACTIVE UNDERSCORE Arg1: #1 Arg2: #2}
\begingroup \catcode`\_=\active\show_\endgroup
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\DefineActiveChar{\^^A}{\long}#1#2{ACTIVE START OF HEADING Arg1: #1 Arg2: #2}
\begingroup \catcode`\^^A=\active\show^^A\endgroup
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\DefineActiveChar{\^^J}{\long}#1#2{ACTIVE LINE FEED Arg1: #1 Arg2: #2}
\begingroup \catcode`\^^J=\active\show^^J\endgroup
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\DefineActiveChar{\^^M}{\long}#1#2{ACTIVE CARRIAGE RETURN Arg1: #1 Arg2: #2}
\begingroup \catcode`\^^M=\active\show^^M\endgroup
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\DefineActiveChar{\~}{\long}#1#2{ACTIVE TILDE Arg1: #1 Arg2: #2}
\begingroup \catcode`\~=\active\show~\endgroup
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\DefineActiveChar{!}{\long}{!}
\begingroup
\catcode`!=\active\show!
\expandafter\show!%
\endgroup
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------

% end in case of running LaTeX:
\csname stop\endcsname
% end in case of running eTeX with plain TeX format:
\bye
```

In case of using Knuthian TeX, where ε-TeX-extensions like `\scantokens` and `\everyeof` are not available, you can, e.g., do:

```tex
% Characters of category 0, 5, 9, 14 and 15 don't make it into explicit 
% character tokens, thus allow syntax both with explicit character tokens
% and control symbol tokens.
%
% E.g., under normal circumstances you can't do
%    \DefineActiveChar{%}{<prefixes like \global>}<parameter text>{<replacement text}%
% , but you can do
%    \DefineActiveChar{\%}{<prefixes like \global><parameter text>{<replacement text}%
% .

% Reading a single space from a line of .tex-input, be it a real text file
% or be it with \scantokens' faking of unexpanded-writing and then inputting
% of a text file, requires special attention because at the time of
% pre-processing a line of .tex-input all space-characters at the end of the
% line get stripped off.
% With some TeX-implementations this is also the case with the horizontal-tab-
% character.
% Thus writing and reading a space-character to/from external text file
% requires appending an additional comment-character.
% At least with writing and reading linefed and carriage return
% special attention might be required, too.

% In LaTeX the \input-primitive is renamed to \@@input and the control sequence
% \input is redefined not to be a macro:
\begingroup
\expandafter\ifx\csname @@input\endcsname\relax
  \endgroup
  \let\myinput=\input
\else
  \endgroup
  \expandafter\let\expandafter\myinput\expandafter=\csname @@input\endcsname
\fi
% In some TeX engines the `\everyeof`-primitive  is available, in others it is not:
\expandafter\ifx\csname everyeof\endcsname\relax
  \def\myeveryeof=#1{}%
\else
  \let\myeveryeof=\everyeof
\fi



\newwrite\scratchwrite
\newtoks\scratchtoks
\def\thescratchtoks{\the\scratchtoks}%

\def\GatherActiveCharacterAsRelax#1{%
  % #1 = active character token to (re)define
  \let#1=\relax\NeutraLizeEOFMarker{#1}%
}%
\def\NeutraLizeEOFMarker#1#2{%
  % #1 = active character token to (re)define
  % #2 = letter X or - in case X is the active character to redefine - active X
  %      ; ensures that in case #1 is space that space is not removed 
  %        during TeX's pre-processing of lines of input
  \endgroup
  \begingroup
  \let#1=\relax
  \scratchtoks={\GatherDefinitionPrefixAndDefine{#1}}%
  \myeveryeof={}%
  \futurelet\scratchmacro\thescratchtoks
}%
\long\def\GatherDefinitionPrefixAndDefine#1#2{%
  % #1 = active character token to (re)define
  % #2 = prefixes for `\def` like `\global` or `\long`
  \endgroup#2\def#1%
}%

\def\DefineActiveChar#1{%
  % #1 = character or one-letter-control-sequence for alphabetic constant
  \begingroup
  \escapechar=-1\relax
  \newlinechar=-1\relax
  \immediate\openout\scratchwrite scratchfile.tex
  \immediate\write\scratchwrite{%
    \ifnum`#1=10 \string^\string^J\else
      \ifnum`#1=13 \string^\string^M\else
       \string#1\fi\fi
     X%
  }%
  \immediate\closeout\scratchwrite
  \endgroup
  \begingroup
  \endlinechar=-1\relax
  \catcode`\^=7\relax
  \catcode`\X=11\relax
  \catcode`#1=\active
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\GatherActiveCharacterAsRelax\expandafter\noexpand
  \myinput "scratchfile.tex" %
}%

{\catcode`!=\active \outer\gdef!{Huh?}}%

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\DefineActiveChar{!}{\long}#1#2{ACTIVE EXCLAMATION MARK Arg1: #1 test Arg2: #2}
\begingroup \catcode`!=\active \show!\endgroup
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\DefineActiveChar{A}{\long}#1#2{ACTIVE A Arg1: #1 test Arg2: #2}
\begingroup \catcode`A=\active \showA\endgroup
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\DefineActiveChar{\!}{\long}#1#2{ACTIVE EXCLAMATION MARK AGAIN Arg1: #1 TEST Arg2: #2}
\begingroup \catcode`!=\active \show!\endgroup
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\DefineActiveChar{\%}{\long}#1#2{ACTIVE PERCENT Arg1: #1 Arg2: #2}
\begingroup \catcode`\%=\active \show%\endgroup
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\DefineActiveChar{\{}{\long}#1#2{ACTIVE CURLY LEFT BRACE Arg1: #1 Arg2: #2}
\begingroup \catcode`\{=\active \show{\endgroup
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\DefineActiveChar{\}}{\long}#1#2{ACTIVE CURLY RIGHT BRACE Arg1: #1 Arg2: #2}
\begingroup \catcode`\}=\active \show}\endgroup
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\DefineActiveChar{\#}{\long}#1#2{ACTIVE HASH Arg1: #1 Arg2: #2}
\begingroup \catcode`\#=\active \show#\endgroup
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\DefineActiveChar{\ }{\long}#1#2{ACTIVE SPACE Arg1: #1 Arg2: #2}
\begingroup \catcode`\ =\active\show \endgroup
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\DefineActiveChar{ }{\long}#1#2{ACTIVE SPACE AGAIN Arg1: #1 Arg2: #2}
\begingroup \catcode`\ =\active\show \endgroup
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\DefineActiveChar{\^^I}{\long}#1#2{ACTIVE HORIZONTAL TAB Arg1: #1 Arg2: #2}
\begingroup \catcode`\^^I=\active\show^^I\endgroup
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\DefineActiveChar{\\}{\long}#1#2{ACTIVE BACKSLASH Arg1: #1 Arg2: #2}
\begingroup \catcode`\/=0 \catcode`\\=\active/show\/endgroup
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\DefineActiveChar{\$}{\long}#1#2{ACTIVE DOLLAR Arg1: #1 Arg2: #2}
\begingroup \catcode`\$=\active\show$\endgroup
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\DefineActiveChar{\&}{\long}#1#2{ACTIVE AMPERSAND Arg1: #1 Arg2: #2}
\begingroup \catcode`\&=\active\show&\endgroup
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\DefineActiveChar{\^}{\long}#1#2{ACTIVE CARET Arg1: #1 Arg2: #2}
\begingroup \catcode`\^=\active\show^\endgroup
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\DefineActiveChar{\_}{\long}#1#2{ACTIVE UNDERSCORE Arg1: #1 Arg2: #2}
\begingroup \catcode`\_=\active\show_\endgroup
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\DefineActiveChar{\^^A}{\long}#1#2{ACTIVE START OF HEADING Arg1: #1 Arg2: #2}
\begingroup \catcode`\^^A=\active\show^^A\endgroup
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\DefineActiveChar{\^^J}{\long}#1#2{ACTIVE LINE FEED Arg1: #1 Arg2: #2}
\begingroup \catcode`\^^J=\active\show^^J\endgroup
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\DefineActiveChar{\^^M}{\long}#1#2{ACTIVE CARRIAGE RETURN Arg1: #1 Arg2: #2}
\begingroup \catcode`\^^M=\active\show^^M\endgroup
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\DefineActiveChar{\~}{\long}#1#2{ACTIVE TILDE Arg1: #1 Arg2: #2}
\begingroup \catcode`\~=\active\show~\endgroup
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\DefineActiveChar{!}{\long}{!}
\begingroup
\catcode`!=\active\show!
\expandafter\show!%
\endgroup
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------

% end in case of running LaTeX:
\csname stop\endcsname
% end in case of running eTeX with plain TeX format:
\bye
```

Let's emphasize again:

This piece of code is an "academic thing". In practice applying `\uccode`+`\uppercase`/`\lccode`+`\lowercase`- or `\scantokens`+`\everyeof`-trickery is much more convenient.